# How can I remove clutter from my page?

Tags: design

I have much clutter on my page:

- a search field

with capital letters and centered:

- latest posts
- latest comments
- archive
- categories
- meta

with smaller and small letters:

- home page administration
- logout
- RSS (post)
- RSS (comment)
- WordPress.org

and

- Proudly powered by WordPress | Theme: Argent by Automattic

On a blog site they would be useful but this is a page for a small business. I do not want any of this.

What is a standard and elegant way to remove these from my pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That clutter is part of the default content added with WordPress and theme installed. You can remove it through the Admin Dashboard UI:

Since you are using the `Argent` theme by Automattic, you need to go to `Appearance` -> `Widgets` -> `Footer Widget Section` and drag all the unnecessary widgets out from it.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the theme you are using. This part with the various widgets is called "sidebar".
A more drastic solution might be to remove it completely.
To do this, remove the code

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

which is usually at the bottom of your pages: index.php, archive.php, page.php etc.
However such drastic changes may need further styling in order for the site to good good afterwards.

If your theme has a file called 'Full width page' or similar, you can use this template as a guide.